# Parsing Header data in R

Tags: r, header

Suppose my file contains this data as the header info:

```
"device.manufacturer","userid","[Total MBytes]","[Num Devices]","[Avg User Age]"
```

when i do

```
data = read.csv(file=file_name, header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

the column names become -

```
> sapply(testframe, class)

device.manufacturer  userid     X.Total.MBytes.      X.Num.Devices.  X.Avg.User.Age. 

"factor"            "factor"           "numeric"           "integer"           "numeric"
```

how do i remove this X character which is coming from the characters [ and ]

Comment: Use `read.csv(..., check.names = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `read.csv(..., check.names = FALSE)` to tell R to not convert your column names to valid R names.

```
dat <- 'userid, [Total MBytes]
1, 100
2, 200'

x <- read.csv(text=dat, header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)

x
  userid [Total MBytes]
1      1            100
2      2            200
```

You will then have to use backticks to refer to these columns

```
x$`[Total MBytes]`
[1] 100 200
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)

names(testframe) <- str_replace_all(names(testframe), "X", "")
```

Comment: but what if X is contained inside the column name, i would not want to remove that.